# How can I pass unicode strings in variables with L (or without)

Tags: c++, c, string, unicode

I have

```
MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Καλημέρα", L"Τέστ", MB_OK|MB_APPLMODAL);
```

That works, but now how can I pass a value that's in my variable "message" and "caption"? I cannot use L anymore because it is a variable,

```
MessageBoxW(hwnd, Lmessage, Lcaption, MB_OK|MB_APPLMODAL); //doesn't work
```

Is there a L(message) or something? message and caption are WCHAR.

Comment: Are you sure that `message` and `caption` are of type `WCHAR`?  That means that they hold a single character each.  Are they possibly `WCHAR*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variables are of type `WCHAR*`, they are naturally in the long string format.

You may pass them to `MessageBoxW` as they are.

```
MessageBoxW(hwnd, message, caption, MB_OK|MB_APPLMODAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Working example:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring message = L"Καλημέρα";
    std::wstring header = L"Τέστ";
    MessageBoxW(NULL, message.c_str(), header.c_str(), MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::wstring s1 = L"Καλημέρα";
std::wstring s2 = L"Τέστ";
MessageBoxW(hwnd, s1, s2, MB_OK|MB_APPLMODAL);
```

To get the C string equivalent:

```
usual_c_string=s1.c_str();
```

[There are various conversions between string types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think there's a version of MessageBoxW that takes `std::wstring`. You'd need to use `.c_str()`.

Answer (score 0):

Better:

```
MessageBoxW(hwnd, boost::widen(message).c_str(), boost::widen(caption).c_str(), MB_OK|MB_APPLMODAL);
```

See utf8everywhere.org for explanation behind this.
Also: I would avoid non-ascii string literals on MSVC. The result of this code might change if the source file is saved in different encoding.